# Create a network when one pc is connected to the Internet via cable and the other via Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I was wondering on how to create a network (share files, etc) when you have a PC which is connected to the router via cable and a laptop, which is connected to the Internet via Wi-Fi. I can't change IP addresses because my internet provider requites that DHCP must be on in the router.

Comment: Your wireless router also functions as a switch, so the PC and laptop should be in the same subnet.  You can verify that by comparing the IP address that is assigned to each.

Comment: @sawdust yes that's right, but how do I create a network between them?

Comment: They just have to be aware of each other.  Windows has workgroups, Win7 and later has Network Discovery and homegroups.  Linux would need DNS in your LAN so that you can use hostnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any computer on the same subnet (e.g. `192.168.1.xxx` or `10.0.0.xxx`) are automatically part of the same network. It shouldn't matter *how* they are connected (i.e. ethernet or wifi) so as long as they are connected to the same router/switch. But in order to communicate, they *do* need a common way to do so (e.g. direct network shares, FTP, web browser, etc).

Note that a common default mask for subnets on home devices is `255.255.255.0`. In short, what this means is e.g. `192.168.1.xxx` and `192.168.2.xxx` are **not** on the same subnet (note the 1 and 2) given this particular mask.

Normally, the above shouldn't be a problem if all the devices are connected to the same router/switch (e.g. all devices should get `192.168.1.xxx` addresses, for instance) but may be an issue if you have two routers/switches on the same network (and different devices are connected to each).

Also note that e.g. `192.168.1.xxx` and `10.0.0.xxx` are **not** the same subnets either (obviously =P ).

**Other Stuff**

- Computers on the same network are always (potentially) accessible to other computers on that network via their local network IP address (e.g `192.168.1.5`, `192.168.1.10`) assuming that they are on the same subnet.
- For computers to be visible under the Windows Network pane, they need to share the same Workgroup. Workgroups are **never** necessary for computers to be considered part of the same basic (IP-based) network and *generally are used **only for sharing via direct network mapped folders and drives***.
- If you are using Windows XP on the same network as Windows Vista or higher, Windows XP machines will not appear in the Windows Network pane. You will need to download the [Link Layer Topology Responder Hotfix](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?/files/file/7891-windowsxp-kb922120-v6-x86-enuexe/) and install it on any computer running Windows XP with Service Pack 2 or 3.
- For sharing files locally without network mapped folders/drives, other solutions include [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and <strike>Bittorrent Sync</strike> [Resilio](https://www.resilio.com/). Both of these solutions have well-supported Windows, Linux and Android applications and both should be able to sync locally.
- FTP can also be a solution for sharing files locally. [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) provides a good free server and client (Windows/Linux) and some programs like [SyncBack Free](https://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/freeware-hub.html) can sync files via FTP as well. FTP is also a possible solution for Android devices on the same network if connected via wifi.
- Games, media servers, etc. will have their own means for sharing data and likely should be able to discover any other computers on the network (as supported by the program) without much intervention.

---

**Windows Workgroups (Extended)**

*Workgroups And Network Pane Visibility In Windows*

As mentioned previously, for computers to be visible under the Windows Network pane, they need to share the same Workgroup.

[image: Windows Workgroup Example]

If you are using Windows XP on the same network as Windows Vista or higher, there have been some changes in how Windows discovers other Windows computers. You will need to download the [Link Layer Topology Responder Hotfix](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?/files/file/7891-windowsxp-kb922120-v6-x86-enuexe/) and install it on any computer running Windows XP with Service Pack 2 or 3. Once installed, this computer should be visible to computers running Vista, 7, 8 or 8.1.

This [thehotfixshare.net](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?showtopic=10753) post links directly to [Version 6](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?/files/file/7891-windowsxp-kb922120-v6-x86-enuexe/) (which is linked above). Version 6 is not publicly available via Microsoft but is recommended.

Under Windows 7, the Workgroup can be set with *Control Panel\System and Security\System*. Select *Advanced System Settings -> Computer Name* tab and clicking the *Change* button to rename the computer/set the Workgroup.

Windows XP instructions are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170806005447/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_network_changename.mspx?mfr=true).

[image: Windows Workgroup Example 2]

*Workgroups and Linux/Android*

Note that it may also be necessary in certain instances for any Linux PCs on the network  to know (or be a part of) a Windows Workgroup. This is usually accomplished on Linux with a program called Samba.

Android devices will show up as connected to the local network in your router/switch settings but almost certainly won't appear under the Network pane in Windows.

*Workgroup Uses*

Workgroups generally are needed only for *direct* (PC to PC, no third party program) file/drive sharing with a Windows PC. Workgroups may, however, also be useful for printer sharing (Samba on Linux can help take care of shared network printers as well).

---

**Sharing Files Directly With Windows Computers**

In Windows, this is usually done via network shares (direct network mapped folders/drives) or Windows [Homegroups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/homegroup-from-start-to-finish-9f802c8c-900f-60fb-826f-6fe06add8fe9#homegroup-start-to-finish) (Windows 7 and 8.1). Note that in Windows 7 Starter and Windows 7 Home Basic, you can join a homegroup, but you can’t create one.

Network shares with Windows require each PC doing the sharing to have the same Workgroup but shares should be available in all versions of Windows. To map/share network drives/folders on XP with Vista or higher, you will need to download the [Link Layer Topology Responder Hotfix](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?/files/file/7891-windowsxp-kb922120-v6-x86-enuexe/) and install it on any computer running Windows XP with Service Pack 2 or 3, as previously mentioned.

Your Network pane should look something like the picture below once you add another computer with the same Workgroup. You may have to right-click -> Refresh under the Network pane in order for the new Windows PC to show up.

[image: Annotated Windows Network View Showing Workgroups]

*Note that the items marked "N Share" and "K Share" are actually default media shares (e.g. My Music) and will open in Windows Media Player in Windows 7.*

**You can access shared folders directly by clicking the COMPUTER icon  under "Computer" (e.g. "N" or "K" in the example above).**

[image: K Share Example]

[image: N Share Example]

If you receive an error opening a network share, you may have to right-click → *Refresh* in the Network pane again. This is especially true if you have added new shared items.

To share a folder or drive in Windows 7, right-click the folder or drive and select *Properties*. Select the *Sharing* tab, and under *Advanced Sharing* check the box to share the folder.

[image: Advanced Sharing Tab Example]

**Note that you must set permissions properly for sharing to work**. If you have too much trouble with custom folder permissions, Windows 7 (by default) comes with a pre-shared "Public" folder that has the correct permissions to allow "drag'n'drop" shared items between computers.

[image: K Public Share Example 1]

[image: K Public Share Example 2]

**Linux**

In Linux, the essential steps to enable network shares with Windows are:

1. Make sure all the computers are on the same network.
2. Make sure your copy of Linux is running Samba. You may need to install it if you don't have it.
3. Make sure Samba has the correct Workgroup settings. Edit /etc/smb.conf (this is the correct file under Ubuntu, at least) and under the [Global] section, make sure the "workgroup= " entry has the appropriate Workgroup name shared between any other networked Windows computers.
4. Restart Samba once you have finished making changes.

A quick overview of the process for Ubuntu is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236746/how-to-turn-on-network-discovery-and-share-between-computers-with-samba).

It may be worthwhile to look at [some Samba configuration examples](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO.html). I also believe most newer versions of Samba come with a web-based configuration tool called SWAT.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was simple and kind of stupid: Both devices had the same name hence the conflict.

Comment: @kulan Ah. Well at least it was an easy fix. =P